# Scp over a proxy with one command from local machine?

Tags: scp

I have my local.machine, the proxy.machine and target.machine. local.machine doesn't have direct contact with target.machine, but needs to go through proxy.machine.

I want to scp a file from target.machine to local.machine. Is this possible to do with just one command from local.machine?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can do this with **ProxyJump**. put this in your `~/.ssh/config` file (creating the file if it does not exist):

```
Host target.machine
User targetuser
HostName target.machine
ProxyJump proxyuser@proxy.machine
```

After saving the file, you can just use

```
ssh target.machine
```

any time you want to connect.  Scp also will work as it also respects the ssh config file.  So will Nautilus, if you're using GNOME and want to use a GUI.

**Old Answer** (for older versions of OpenSSH)

```
Host target.machine
User targetuser
HostName target.machine
ProxyCommand ssh proxyuser@proxy.machine nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Just a quick note. If you are using an alternative identity file via the -i command line option for ssh, you need to specify that option for both the ProxyCommand configuration and the ssh command line.

Comment: 3 things that might help, 1) it would help if you also showed the `Host proxy.machine` lines in the same `~/.ssh/config` file, 2) Mention whether these commands can be nested (ie. client connects to proxy host 1 which connects to proxy host 2 which connects to...target) and 3) what `nc %h %p` means

Comment: How can we copy from local machine to target machine with proxy?

Comment: Newer versions of OpenSSH have acquired the `ProxyJump` option for specifying the `proxyuser@proxy.machine`.

Answer (score 34):

You can now* do this as a one-liner, **without requiring** `nc` anywhere:

```
scp -o "ProxyCommand ssh pcreds@proxy.machine -W %h:%p" tcreds@target.machine:file .
```

**Explanation**

`pcreds` and `tcreds` represent your proxy and target credentials if required (`username`, `username:password`, etc.).

This is possible because of a built-in netcat-like ability, removing the requirement for `nc` on the intermediate host. Using `ssh -W host:port` sets up a tunnel to the specified host and port and connects it to stdin/stdout, and then `scp` runs over the tunnel.

The `%h` and `%p` in the `ProxyCommand` are replaced with the target host and port from the outer `scp` command, to save you having to repeat them.

For even more convenience, you can configure the proxy in your ssh configuration:

```
Host target.machine
    ProxyCommand ssh pcreds@proxy.machine -W %h:%p
```

and from then on just do

```
scp tcreds@target.machine:file .
```

* *since OpenSSH 5.4 - [released March 2010](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4)*

Comment: Verified this indeed works well, and does not leave stale NC processes laying around on the proxy machine.

Comment: Where can I specify the port of the proxy ?

Comment: @Marged I'm not in a position to try it here at the moment, but I think you should be able to include `-p <portnum>` before the `-W` in either method to specify the proxy port

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that the -i option (if you need it) goes *inside* the quotes.  The proxy ssh does not by default use the same private key specified by any -i option supplied directly to scp.  I guess that is obvious when you think about it.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't mind using rsync instead of scp, you can use the following one-liner:

```
rsync -v --rsh "ssh proxy.machine ssh" target.machine:/remote/file /local/dir/
```

(you'll need passwordless access to the proxy machine)

Answer (score 22):

You can do it in one command, but you need netcat (nc) installed on the proxy machine:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh poxyuser@proxy.machine nc -w 1 %h 22" targetuser@target.machine
```

Comment: Nice try, but where should I add the username for proxy and for login?

Comment: Jzst before the machine names, with an @. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 9):

```
$ ssh -f -N -L <localport>:<target.machine:port> user@proxy.machine
$ scp target-user@local.machine:/remote/file -P <localport> .
```

OK, actually two commands...

Comment: How can I specify the port of my proxy ? In my case `8080`

Comment: @Marged add `-p <portnumber>` to your ssh command

Answer (score 8):

A one-liner?  Not off the top of my head.  You need to establish a proxy first and you can't do that with scp by itself.

When doing it manually, I open up a screen session for my tunnel:

`screen -S tunnel`

Screen is used to keep the tunnel going in a background shell.  Use any technique you want to keep the tunnel open in the background (@weeheavy's answer is probably the simplest).  Once in the screen session I start my tunnel like so

`ssh -L 2222:target.machine:22 [user@]proxy.machine`

To break that down, that basically says "On my local machine, open port 2222 and any connetion hitting localhost:2222 is proxied through proxy.machine to target.machine:22"

Once you've got the ssh connection and tunnel established, detach from the screen session with "C-a d".  To get back to that screen session, type `screen -raAd tunnel`

Once you are back in your original shell your scp command will look like

`scp -P 2222 localhost:your/file/on/target.machine   local/path`

Remember that localhost port 2222 is really just a tunnel going to target.machine.

Answer (score 4):

Appears that **scp** supports the `-o` option just like **ssh** does, though I'm not sure how to pass it a proxy username/password:

```
scp -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p" remote_user@remote_host:remote_path local_path
```

If you get `nc: invalid option -- X` see [my stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616021/32453)

Comment: dope bro, worked straightaway :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
scp -o "ProxyCommand ssh user@myproxyserver.com nc %h %p" your.filename username@yourdestination.yourdomain.com:/whatever_location
```

Comment: or possibly username:password here?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
ssh user@proxy.machine "ssh user@target.machine 'cat > file'" < file
```

But it won't work if your proxy.machine needs to ask you password (that SSH is not in a TTY, so askpass will fail).

If you have more than one file, you could use tar like this (untested, I usually use a netcat that way):

```
tar cf - file1 file2 folder1/ | ssh user@proxy.machine "ssh user@target.machine 'tar xvf -'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution 
to transfer a *source_file* from the *source_host* to a *destination_host* via a *proxy_host*:

Log in on the *proxy_server*:

```
ssh login@proxy_host
```

From the proxy server, transfer the *source_file* from the *source_host* to the *destination_host* (you can type this as one line, omitting the `\`,
or as two lines, as shown below):

```
scp login@source_host:/path_to_source_file \
  login@destination_host:/path_to_destination_directory
```

This requires that the login on the source_host to the proxy_host uses an rsa_key.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this article and found an answer which works for me. (Because the answers above don't work for me).

How to `scp` a file through an intermediate host (a.k.a. jump host)
http://mperdikeas.github.io/networking.html.files/scp-a-file-through-jump-host.html

And my answer is as below:

```
scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p {username}@{proxy_IP}" \
        {source_file} {remote_username}@{remote_IP}:{remote_file_path}
```

Example:

```
scp -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p ubuntu@10.60.10.145" \
        archive.gz wise@35.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/wise/archive.gz
```

I hope this answer could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to use public keys you will need something like this.

```
Host target-machine
  User          target-user
  HostName      target.example.com
  IdentityFile  /path/to/file.pem
  ProxyCommand  ssh bastion -W %h:%p

Host bastion
  User         bastion-user
  HostName     bastion.example.com
  IdentityFile /path/to/file.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ProxyJump on the command line as well:

```
scp -o "ProxyJump proxyUser@proxy.machine" src dest
```

The sintax is the same as for scp, just add -o option with ProxyJump command. The same works for SSH as well.

NOTE: you need to have access without password to proxyUser@proxy.machine.

In order to achieve this use this command:

```
ssh-copy-id proxyUser@proxy.machine
```

confirm, insert the password and the job is done.