# How do I SCP a file through an intermediate server?

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunnel

I'm using Ccygwin on WinXP (with the bash shell).  I want to SCP a file from my localhost to a remote machine -- host2.  However, I can only SSH to an intermediate machine -- host1, and then from there SSH to host2.  (Note, I ccan't access host2 from my localhost).

I thought tunneling was my answer, but when I try to set up a tunnel

```
ssh -L 9999:localhost:9998 dalvarado@host1 'ssh -L 9998:localhost:1234 -N dalvarado@host2'
```

But after typing this command and hitting enter, the system just hangs.  What is the proper way to setup a tunnel and then SCP a file after?

Thanks, -

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/174160/scp-over-a-proxy-with-one-command-from-local-machine - see my answer below for a summary.

Comment: From user [Meir D](http://superuser.com/users/687829/meir-d): Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scp files via intermediate host](https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host)

Answer (score 35):

Since [OpenSSH 7.3](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/ed877ef653847d056bb433975d731b7a1132a979), you can use `-J` or `-o ProxyJump` to specify the bastion/jump host. Therefore, to SSH to `node2` via `node1`:

```
ssh -J you@node1 you@node2
```

SCP doesn't have the `-J` argument, but it does allow `-o`, so this works:

```
scp -o ProxyJump=you@node1 file.txt you@node2:~
```

Comment: The `-J` was added to `scp` (and `sftp`) in [OpenSSH 8.0](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.0).

Answer (score 22):

This has already been answered best [here](https://superuser.com/questions/174160/scp-over-a-proxy-with-one-command-from-local-machine).

To summarize: 
put the following in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host target.machine
User          targetuser
HostName      target.machine
ProxyCommand  ssh proxyuser@proxy.machine nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

and then simply `scp` to target.machine any time you want to proxy via proxy.machine!

Also works for `ssh`, so will save you time ssh-ing to the target machine too.

Credit should go to user24925 who answered this in 2011.

Answer (score 15):

To set up a SSH tunnel, use the following format:

```
ssh -L 9999:host2:22 user@host1
```

This command connects to `host1` as `user` and tunnels port 9999 on the computer issuing the command to port 22 on `host2`. `-N` is optional, or you can use something like `top` or `watch` to keep the session alive if needed.

Then, simply `scp` to host2 on localhost:9999.

Comment: When I run this command, am I supposed to end up getting logged in to host1?  Also, after running this command, I opened another bash shell, and ran "scp hello.txt localhost:9999", but got a "ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused" error.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you run this command, you will be connected to host1, yes. Your `scp` command syntax is incorrect though. Try this `scp -P 9999 hello.txt user@localhost:/path/to/destination/file` where `user` is the user on `host2` that you want login as.

Comment: @Rain, you could put this example in the main answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could first scp the file to host1, like this:

```
scp file dalvarado@host1:.
```

Then do this to get it to host2:

```
ssh -t dalvarado@host1 'scp file dalvarado@host2:.'
```

The `-t` option to `ssh` forces it to allocate a pseudo-terminal, which may make it easier for `scp` on host1 to prompt you for a passphrase/password.  If you have ssh-agent running and configured everywhere, you shouldn't be prompted for a passphrase/password.

I offer this alternative, because if you used a tunnel, you'd still need two commands: one to setup the tunnel and one to copy the file through it.  This seems simpler.

Comment: Fantastic solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

Now you can send your file over ssh tunnel with -J option

```
scp -J proxy-host your-file destination-host:[directory]
```

If you need to specify port on the proxy host you have to use -P option

```
scp -P port-number -J proxy-host your-file destination-host:[directory]
```

Finally if you need to send files from subdirectories you can use -r option

```
scp -r -P port-number -J proxy-host your-file destination-host:[directory]
```

The order in which you specify the options matters!

Answer (score 0):

To copy from remote C, through jump box B to your local host A

```
scp -J username@B username@C:/file/location /file/path/on/local
```