# How to access the SSH through another server

Tags: linux, ssh, routing, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a Linux server (**A**) (With IP X.X.X.X) that's accept SSH (in port X) only from another Linux server (**B**) with specific IP Y.Y.Y.Y. Obviously, if I login in the server **B** (From whatever IP) I can SSH the server **A**.

It is possible to access the server **A** through server **B** using a routing or forwarding from any IP?

I'm expecting to open a SSH connection in a specific port in server **B** and this will route the traffic to server **A**

Comment: Do you *need* to use routing or is an ssh-protocol specific solution also ok?

Comment: Actually, I need to use SFTP  (SSH File Transfer Protocol) from my office/home to access the files on server A.

Comment: @criztovyl I have to create a VPN (HOME/OFFICE => SERVER B) in this case?

Comment: Yes, an ssh-protocol solution is also okay.

Comment: If you can access Server B from your home/office, you do not need to create a VPN.
Do you have an SFTP client in mind you intend to use?

Comment: Yes, I can access the server B from my office/home and intend to use Filezilla client in this case.

Comment: The credentials you use to access the server A from B, are they stored on the server B? (If you use a password then the answer is no.)

Comment: No (both servers have different passwords and are not stored)

Comment: What OS are you on, how open are you to switching tools? IMO best protocol/client feature to use is a jump/proxy host, [but filezilla does not seem support that](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=54317).

Comment: the alternative is a ssh port-forwarding, but you will need to use a additional program/client here to establish that port-forwarding.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1313935/432690) help? Note there's a useful comment below it.

Comment: @criztovyl If you can suggest me another SFTP client that's supports ssh port-forwarding for me is okay

Comment: What OS are you on? What is the SSH client you use normally?

Comment: The client OS is Fedora Linux. To transfer files we use Filezilla and the default ssh client (/usr/bin/ssh) in terminal for remote SSH connections.

Comment: I have solved this using nginx upstream. What do you think, is this a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is called SSH Bastion and you can easily configure it by creating a ssh config file inside you .ssh directory. A good description is here: https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-bastion-host/

Something like this shall made the trick (assuming that you want to connect to to server A from server C, you create a config file in server C):

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host X.X.X.X
   User serverAusername
   ProxyJump Y.Y.Y.Y
```

make sure that server B /etc/ss/sshd_config file has the correct settings as per the above link.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to solve this case is using nginx upstream in server **B**.

First, make sure to load the **nginx stream module**

```
load_module '/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_module.so';
```

And add the proxy configuration as below:

```
stream  {
    upstream ssh {
        server {server-a-ip}:22;
    }

    server  {
        listen {my-non-standard-port};
        proxy_pass ssh;
    }
}
```

Then you can connect to server **A**:

```
ssh username@{server-b-ip} -p {my-non-standard-port}
```

Of course, better allow only your public IPs to access the server **B** in port {my-non-standard-port}

Comment: As you note this puts the ssh of server A into a similar exposed position like B. If that is not a problem, this is a solution. An alternative to forwarding the port on this level could be to firewalld/firewall-cmd.