# ssh/scp from client to target through proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, scp, openssh

I have a target host and proxy host and client host, the client host could not connect to the target host directly, even with command ping. I am wondering if there is anyway for me to ssh or scp from client to target host directly. I googled and found this link may help:

[Scp over a proxy with one command from local machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/174160/scp-over-a-proxy-with-one-command-from-local-machine)

But I am not sure whether this method would still work if the client could not ping the target host. I tries this method, but not working. Is there any other choices?

Comment: First, a sanity chcek: do you have the `http_proxy` environment variable set?

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to ping a remote machine can just mean that *ICMP* is blocked or ignored. This doesn't have to prevent other connections. There are several ways for setting up a proxy for SSH, for example by using [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) or [httptunnel](http://www.nocrew.org/software/httptunnel/).